# How to change the title of SiteCollection

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to change the title of one of `SiteCollection` in my `SharePoint Online` with the trial account. But didn't found any functional button or feature can make it. Please kindly tell me where it can be made.

The `SiteCollection` I want to change is the created by default when I first log into the `SharePoint Online`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

1. Open Site and click the gear on the top right bar.
2. Choose Site settings.
3. Click Title, description, and logo under Look and Feel.
4. Type in the name and click OK.

Comment: But why this doen't work for the SiteCollection ` https://beyondhard-my.sharepoint.com/`? the others SiteCollection title can be changed by the way you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: the main root is the domain. This is why you cannot change it

Comment: @susan Forgive me I am a newbie. Could you please tell me what is `the main root`. thanks.

Comment: main root is your domain, if you have purchased a subscription with Microsoft you have given the name of your company or a chosen name, let's say CompanyZ. Therefore your domain address for the default site collection is ... companyz.sharepoint.com

Comment: any other site will be

companyz.sharepoint.com/sites/abc

companyz.sharepoint.com/sites/def

companyz.sharepoint.com/sites/etc



therefore not only you cannot change the root without contacting Microsoft, but from the dark portion of your screenshot you are trying to change the name of the SEARCH default site collection. I strongly advise you not to.

Comment: Also, the part sharepoint.com cannot be change at all.

Comment: @susan As you said,It seems beyondhard.sharepoint.com is the main root. I didn't know why `SharePoint Online` create a sitecollection named `beyondhard-my.sharepoint.com` automatically. I am not going to change the `Domain name` beyondhard to something else. I just want to change the displaying title of it. thanks.

Comment: beyondhard-my.sharepoint.com is your 'main root' You can avoid using it and create another site collection that will be beyondhard-my.sharepoint.com/sites/something else. Maybe you are in trial and have some limitations